# Regular expression from the first number block after an opening bracket. Repeat after closing the parenthesis

Tags: python, regex

I've been trying to solve this problem for a while now, but I just can't get it right.

I would like the following string to be split up so that I get the first block of numbers after the opening bracket. If another bracket is opened before the previous one is closed, the following numerical block is invalid.

Test String:

`[(16908,76,(2585,0,0),(),()),(18404,74,(),(),()),(16823,66,(),(),()),(0,0,(),(),()),(16905,76,(),(),()),(16910,76,(),(),()),(16909,76,(2585,0,0),(),()),(16906,76,(1887,0,0),(),()),(16911,76,(1886,0,0),(),()),(16907,76,(1887,0,0),(),()),(19384,83,(),(),()),(19898,68,(),(),()),(13965,63,(),(),()),(11815,58,(),(),()),(13340,63,(849,0,0),(),()),(19896,65,(1900,0,0),(),()),(19910,65,(1900,0,0),(),()),(17069,69,(),(),()),(0,0,(),(),())],[]`

Valid number blocks:
`16908, 18404, 16823, 16905, etc`

Invalid number blocks:
`2585, 2585, 1887, etc`

The valid blocks should be displayed separated by commas.
In this example the numbers have all five digits, but this can vary from 0 - 8 digits.
The use of such `(\d{0,8})` does not look very adequate to me.

I am absolutely not a regex professional and would be happy about any kind of impulse or help that brings me to my goal.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My feeling here is that this is really the job for a formal _parser_, rather than trying to come up with some kind of regex.  Not my downvote though.

Comment: I would recommend to try "ast.literal_eval" on it and process the result.

Comment: Why isn't `0` from `(0,0,(),(),())` a valid number block?

Comment: Good Point @TelmoTrooper. That's a valid number as well.

Comment: Yet you have `(16908,76,(2585,0,0),(),())` 16908 listed as valid.

Comment: Something to think about. `If another bracket is opened before the previous one is closed` Python _re_ doesn't support balanced text. Basically what you're looking for can't be accomplished with this engine. _It can be with the `regex` engine though._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do it with two regexes:

```
from re import findall, search

text = "[(16908,76,(2585,0,0),(),()),(18404,74,(),(),()),(16823,66,(),(),()),(0,0,(),(),()),(16905,76,(),(),()),(16910,76,(),(),()),(16909,76,(2585,0,0),(),()),(16906,76,(1887,0,0),(),()),(16911,76,(1886,0,0),(),()),(16907,76,(1887,0,0),(),()),(19384,83,(),(),()),(19898,68,(),(),()),(13965,63,(),(),()),(11815,58,(),(),()),(13340,63,(849,0,0),(),()),(19896,65,(1900,0,0),(),()),(19910,65,(1900,0,0),(),()),(17069,69,(),(),()),(0,0,(),(),())],[]"

matches = findall(r'\(\w+(?!\().+?\)', text) // find valid blocks

blocks = []

for match in matches:
    blocks.append(search('\d+', match).group()) // get first number in every match (block number)

print(blocks)
```

Output is:

```
['16908', '18404', '16823', '0', '16905', '16910', '16909', '16906', '16911', '16907', '19384', '19898', '13965', '11815', '13340', '19896', '19910', '17069', '0']
```

Is this the behavior you want?

Comment: More than perfect! Sometimes is less more :)

Answer (score 1):

Is this regex want you need `r'\((\d{1,8}),\d+(?:,\(\d*,?\d*,?\d*\)){3}\)'`?

Demo:
https://regex101.com/r/oz0bdE/1

Python code:

```
import re

string = '[(16908,76,(2585,0,0),(),()),(18404,74,(),(),()),(16823,66,(),(),()),(0,0,(),(),()),(16905,76,(),(),()),(16910,76,(),(),()),(16909,76,(2585,0,0),(),()),(16906,76,(1887,0,0),(),()),(16911,76,(1886,0,0),(),()),(16907,76,(1887,0,0),(),()),(19384,83,(),(),()),(19898,68,(),(),()),(13965,63,(),(),()),(11815,58,(),(),()),(13340,63,(849,0,0),(),()),(19896,65,(1900,0,0),(),()),(19910,65,(1900,0,0),(),()),(17069,69,(),(),()),(0,0,(),(),())],[]'

matches = re.findall(r'\((\d{1,8}),\d+(?:,\(\d*,?\d*,?\d*\)){3}\)', string)
print(matches)
```

Output:

```
['16908', '18404', '16823', '0', '16905', '16910', '16909', '16906', '16911', '16907', '19384', '19898', '13965', '11815', '13340', '19896', '19910', '17069', '0']
```

Comment: Nice solution as well and has the exact behavior I was looking for. Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to verify the structure of the string you can match a very simple regular expression that reflects the observation that the strings of digits of interest are the only ones that are immediately preceded by a left parenthesis.

```
re'(?<=\()\d{1,8}'
```

`(?<=\()` is a *positive lookbehind* that asserts that the current position in the string is immediately preceded by a left parenthesis.

[Matching regex](https://regex101.com/r/alqPNL/1/)

If you need to verify the structure of the string as well you could use the following regular expression. I've assumed the string ends `"],[]"`. If that is not the case an adjustment is of course necessary.

```
r'^\[(?:(?:(?<!\[),|)\(\d{1,8},\d+(?:,\((?:\d+(?:,\d+)+)?\))*\))*\],\[\]$'
```

[Verification regex](https://regex101.com/r/alqPNL/3/)

For verification Pyton's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
^                : match beginning of string
\[               : match '['
(?:              : begin non-capture group
  (?:            : begin non-capture group
    (?<!\[)      : use negative lookbehind to assert current
                   position is not preceded by '['
    ,            : match ','
  |              : or
                 : match an empty string
  )              : end non-capture group
  \(\d{1,8},\d+  : match '(', 1-8 digits, ',', 1+ digits
  (?:            : begin non-capture group
    ,\(          : match ',('
    (?:          : begin non-capture group
      \d+        : match 1+ digits
      (?:,\d+)   : match ',', 1+ digits in a non-capture group
      +          : execute non-capture group 1+ times
    )?           : end non-capture group and make it optional
    \)           : match ')'
  )*             : end non-capture group and execute it 0+ times
  \)             : match ')'
)*               : end non-capture group and execute it 0+ times
\],\[\]$         : match '],[]' at end of string
```